# Is there a cross-platform C signal library available(better open-sourced)?

Tags: c, windows, linux, cross-platform, signals

I'm recently working on a project in which I need to port a portion of Linux C code to Windows.  The code uses Linux signal mechanism(I mean the "sigaction", "sigprocmast", etc...) which is not well supported on Windows.

**Is there a C/C++ library available that implements the cross-platform signal mechanism(better open-sourced)?**  Currently I just need the library to **support Linux & Windows**.

I think **this question would also make sense to you** because you might be given a similar task some day.

One of my colleagues told me that ACE is a powerful library that implements cross-platform signal mechanism perfectly, but he said it's a huge library and would really take some time to study it.  My project doesn't give me too much time so I'm trying to look for a **light-weight** and **easy-to-study** signal library.  (Hmm.. well, if the libraries you know about are all pretty big, please also tell me. :-)

I've done a lot of research on this subject with Google but I couldn't find what I want.  Here is **what I have done so far**:

1. Searched in Stackoverflow.com.  People asked a lot of details about how to use signals in Linux but nobody seemed to ask about cross-platform signal implementation.
2. Or, in Stackoverflow.com, people asked a mechamism called "signal-slot".  I don't think that is what I need.
3. Searched in entire google.  I tried the key words "C signal "cross platform" OR cross-platform -game -python -gui -audio -digital -analysis -slot -image -processing -socket -time -directmedia" but couldn't find what I want.

Please help!  Thanks!

Comment: There's a small note at http://mao-yu.com/notes/sys_signal/ concerning implementing one of the signals.

Comment: @vissi: good link. Sadly, it just handle the Ctrl-C (SIGINT) signal. Windows has nothing that maps directly to Posix signals, AFAIK.

Comment: @vissi: Thanks, vissi, but I had found that link as well and it doesn't help me very much.  But thank you all the same :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try porting your library using cygwin. There are several applications following the same way.

Answer (score 3):

I've come over the problem some time ago. The big problem is that there is NO paradigm equivalent with *signals* on windows. The way it is done is just different.

I found that when I wanted to port some software from Linux to windows using *pthread* library. I was glad to find out that there a port of *pthread* ! Great ! But they explicitly state in their doc that have only implemented the `pthread_kill(signal)` API call with signal 0 (IIRC), with only gives you the state of the thread (eg it is running or not).

When you look at portable thread libs (like in boost) they use *interruption points* to handle the difference between the two models/paradigm.

To conclude, it depends on how signals are used in the application you're porting. You can surely port some behavior handled by signal on Linux to windows, but you certainly can not port the signal system 'as is'.

And I've found the hard way that it is not easy to do that when you use signal to interrupt sleeping system calls ^^

If there is a solution, I'm glad to hear from other answers ^^

my2c

Comment: +1.  Different platforms do things differently.  Windows is not Unix; not even close.

Comment: @luke: Yes, and signal is one of the core difference, particularly regarding interruption of system calls ...

Comment: I agree it's pretty difficult to port the signal stuff in an "as-is" way.  I think I'll try to port the behaviours to Windows.

Comment: @rob: In fact my current conclusion is that it's impossible for things like interrupting system calls as there is nothing like that in windows, AFAIK. As some well known portable libs seems not to use signal to do this sort of things, I'm pretty confidant on this. By the way how are signals used in your app ?

Comment: What apache apr ? http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__signal.html

Note : I'm far from being up to speed with posix systems and signal. So the link may be complete bonkers.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably look into CYGWIN.

The problem with signals on Windows is that they just don't exist.  Windows isn't POSIX and uses an almost entirely different methodology when it comes to application management.  Its like asking where the spark plugs are on a hang-glider, there aren't any:)

Answer (score 0):

Just doing some research and found [Writing POSIX-Standard Code](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463220.aspx) on the Microsoft TechNet.

I looks like it gives some more (longer) reasoned details about what is similar and what is different, and what can, can't and could be done in one's code for porting Unix/Linux code.

It is part of a bigger set of info (see the hierarchy side bar)which I haven't had time to even browse...

Beyond CYGWIN, there is also [MSYS and MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

There also appears to be a bit of friction (or more often indifference) between the communities, with few folks spanning the divide.